# Storing form field data in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a react form below (which is a child component) that I need to store the selected options of (radio button and input text value selected), which will be accessible from a subsequent page for submission. I'm able to log out the selected radio option on click, but how can I store the selected values on submit, which will then be accessible for submission through a REST API on a subsequent page?

```
class CancelSurvey extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      reasons: []
    }
    this.processData = this.processData.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.fetchContent(this.processData)
  }

  fetchContent (cb) {
    superagent
      .get('/api/endpoint')
      .then(cb)
  }

  processData (data) {
    this.setState({
      reasons: data.body
    })
  }

  setReason(event) {
    this.props.receiveReason(event.target.value);
  }

  render (props) {
    const content = this.props.config.contentStrings
    const reason = this.state.reasons.map((reason, i) => {
      return (
        <div className='fieldset__item' key={i} onChange={this.setReason.bind(this)}>
          <label>{reason.client_reason}</label>
          <input type='radio'
            id={reason.reason_id}
            value={reason.client_reason}
            name='reason' />
        </div>
      )
    })

    return (
      <div className='survey'>
        <h2 className='heading md'>heading</h2>
        <p className='subpara'>subheading</p>
        <form id='exit-survey'>
          <fieldset className='fieldset'>
            { reason }
            <label>Other reason not included above:</label>
            <input type='radio'
              id='other'
              value='other'
              name='reason' />
            <input className='valid'
              type='text'
              id='user[name]'
              name='user[name]'
              value='plaholder text' />
          </fieldset>
        <div className='footer-links'>
          <button href='/' className='btn btn--primary btn--lg'>cancel</button>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CancelSurvey
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a prop such as `this.props.reason` and set it to be the reason on form submit.

Then in the parent component use `(reason) => this.setState({reason})` as a handler, such as onSubmit.

EXAMPLE ---

in the parent

```
<CancelSurvey 
receiveReason={ (reason) => this.setState({reason}) } 
/>
```

in the component

```
setReason(event) {
    this.props.receiveReason(event.target.value);
}
```

Which will allow you to pass the new state object `reason` to another component.

EDIT ---

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/deMrpV?editors=0010) that I've created using your code, I've commented out some functions and code that would cause an error on codepen, if you copy and paste the codepen please remember to adjust it back.

You can see that I'm using the state to handle the values and status of the inputs. I've created a new button that calls `setReason` and console logs the reason the user has selected. To receive this in the parent component you just need to uncomment the `receiveReason` call.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, but could you provide an example?

Comment: I've updated my question with your answer, but still unsure of how to access the form fields stored in `setReason` that can be simply logged out for now to test form submission, and then posted.

Comment: I've added a new example in my answer, hope that helps you.